# Removing image src attribute

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

Removing the `src` attribute on an `image` tag doesn't seem to redraw the view on iOS(7) or Android (KitKat). Neither does changing the attribute to a blank value. Desktop browsers work as expected.

This DOES remove the attribute but the view doesn't reflect the change:
`$('#imgPreview').removeAttr('src');`

This DOES change the attribute but the view doesn't reflect the change:
`$('#imgPreview').attr('src','');`

If the attribute is changed to a valid image path, the view DOES update:
`$('#imgPreview').attr('src','http://some/image/path.jpg');`

I have a simple test case [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tv89V/7/) that shows the issue.

Is there a way that I can force a redraw after changing the `src` attribute to a blank value or removing the `src` attribute altogether?

Comment: Have you tried with `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`?

Comment: why not detach the image if it has no src?

Comment: @Satpal It appears to be the same: http://jsfiddle.net/Tv89V/8/

Comment: @Pete No reason really other that the code I am working with is as above. I'd rather know why this doesn't work

Comment: Could you try: `$('#imgPreview').removeAttr('src').hide().show(0);` to force element redraw?! Or maybe setting `z-index` would be enough

Comment: @A.Wolff hide / show works well. As does changing css attributes, though they need to be reset each time or changed to a different value. Add as an answer if you like. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force element redraw using this kind of snippet:

```
$.fn.redraw = function(){
    return this.hide().show(0);
};
```

Or maybe better:

```
$.fn.redraw = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var zIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
        $(this).css('z-index',-1).css('z-index',zIndex);
    });
};
```

Then use it as e.g:

```
$('#imgPreview').removeAttr('src').redraw();
```

Comment: Spot on. Cheers! Though I'd still love to know why this is even necessary